# If you discard Immortal Phoenix, does it return to your hand?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I have an [Immortal Phoenix](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=469885) in my hand, and an opponent casts a [Reaper of Night](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=473064) (the adventure, not the creature). If I discard the Phoenix, will it return to my hand?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it won't. *Dies* is a term with a very specific meaning: it means to be put in the graveyard *from the battlefield*. If it is put there from your hand, the ability won't trigger.

> 700.4. The term dies means “is put into a graveyard from the battlefield.”